# Do Regula DLLs must have a CWinApp-derived class?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc

I'm reading msdn pages introducing DLLs in C++, in both [Regular DLLs Statically Linked to MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f22wcbea.aspx) and [Regular DLLs Dynamically Linked to MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c674tx.aspx), it says:

> Regular DLLs must have a `CWinApp`-derived class and a single object of
>   that application class, as does an MFC application. However, the
>   `CWinApp` object of the DLL does not have a main message pump, as does
>   the `CWinApp` object of an application.

Is this true?

I'm actually using [XLW](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/) (an open source application that wraps the Excel C API in simple C++ interfaces ) to build XLL plug-ins for Excel.

Howcome I couldn't find any `CWinApp` in either the codes generated by XLW or the XLW source code?

ps: Notes on XLW -- basically, if you write a library consists of `mylib.h` and `mylib.cpp`, XLW will parse `mylib.h` and generate `xlwmylib.cpp`; compile and link all three files together, will generate a `mylib.xll`, that can be imported by Excel as an add-in; then Excel can call functions defined in `mylib.h` as normal Excel function, either in formular or in VBA.

Comment: *"Is this true?"* - Uhm... yes. Why would you second-guess the documentation? The problem is, that you are looking at rules **specific to MFC**. Those rules do not apply to code that doesn't use MFC. You could have simply clicked the link [Non-MFC DLLs: Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x2ta076.aspx) on the left-hand side of the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm a bit lost here... what makes it to be a **MFC DLL**? for example, in the "Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx), the MathLibrary used `<iostream>` from Microsoft library, does this make it a **`MFC` DLL**?

Comment: You added the [tag:mfc] tag. When you hover over it, it'll offer to show you [more information](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mfc/info). MFC is just a random class library. `<iostream>`, on the other hand, is a Standard C++ header file, unrelated to MFC. Microsoft ships a Standard C++ implementation (compiler and support libraries). Both of these are unrelated to MFC.

Comment: @IInspectable is it correct that there are 3 kinds of libraries provided by microsoft, the MFC library (for Windows GUI programming, an OO abstraction on top of Win32 API), the C Run-time library, and the C++Standard Library (STL)?

Comment: The interesting libraries are: `1` The Windows API. It exposes the OS' system services, and it is the (low-level) programming interface for all native Windows applications. `2` The CRT and C++ Standard Library. Those are part of the compiler, and allow C and C++ code to compile and run on the Windows platform. All other libraries are not strictly required to write standard Windows applications. As such, MFC is optional. But if you use it, additional rules apply. You probably won't benefit from MFC when using XLW.